# Sending Email With Multiple File Paths From For Loop

Tags: python

I have a for loop that inserts data from spreadsheets (xlsx files) at a shared location into a database table. After the run is complete I would like to send an email with the processed file names to a distribution list. Now I know how to do this in the for loop but I only want to send a single email. My main problem is that I am unsure of how to store the file names and then after the loops are done, send the email with a list of all file names. I was thinking of doing this in an array but that seems inefficient. I was also looking at StringIO (or cStringIO).

```
import xlrd
import pymssql
import glob
import os
import shutil
import uuid
from time import gmtime, strftime


path = 'c:\\Test\\'
source = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xls*'))
print source

if not source:
    exit()

for sf in source:


    # Establish a SQL connection
    database = pymssql.connect("localhost", "username", "password",
                               "testdb")

    # Get the cursor, which is used to traverse the database, line by line
    cursor = database.cursor()

    #Parse name from file
    name = sf
    delivery,type,name,date = name.split("_",3)

    # Create the INSERT INTO sql query
    query = """INSERT INTO testdb(value1,value2) VALUES (%s, %s)"""


    # Open the workbook and define the worksheet
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(sf)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Test")
    date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    assetuuid = str(uuid.uuid1())

    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        value1 = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
        value2 = sheet.cell(r,9).value
        values = (value1, value2)
        cursor.execute(query, values)

    shutil.move(sf, 'c:\\Test\\Archive\\')

    # Close the cursor
    cursor.close()

    # Commit the transaction
    database.commit()

# Close the database connection
database.close()
```

Comment: As you insert the data, append the filenames to a list object. Then, when the loop terminates, just dump the list of filenames in to the email body.

Comment: Thanks David, I added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple to capture the files which you used:

```
import xlrd
import pymssql
import glob
import os
import shutil
import uuid
from time import gmtime, strftime


path = 'c:\\Test\\'
source = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xls*'))
print source

if not source:
    exit()

files_used = []  ## this will contain list of file names which we processed

for sf in source:


    # Establish a SQL connection
    database = pymssql.connect("localhost", "username", "password",
                               "testdb")

    # Get the cursor, which is used to traverse the database, line by line
    cursor = database.cursor()

    #Parse name from file
    name = sf
    delivery,type,name,date = name.split("_",3)

    # Create the INSERT INTO sql query
    query = """INSERT INTO testdb(value1,value2) VALUES (%s, %s)"""


    # Open the workbook and define the worksheet
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(sf)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Test")
    date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    assetuuid = str(uuid.uuid1())
    # Append this filename to our list:
    files_used.append(sf)
    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        value1 = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
        value2 = sheet.cell(r,9).value
        values = (value1, value2)
        cursor.execute(query, values)

    shutil.move(sf, 'c:\\Test\\Archive\\')

    # Close the cursor
    cursor.close()

    # Commit the transaction
    database.commit()

# Close the database connection
database.close()

"""
Now that you're done processing the files, 
you can send your email using the files_used list object
"""
```

As for sending the email, do you have any existing code to send email? (If not, find some and attempt to implement it -- there should be many examples and libraries you can use to do this sort of thing).

The email should take the list `files_used` and can add the list values to the email body simply by joining the list elements:

```
"""
Assumes you have some name like 'email_body' which 
you are using to construct the email contents, then
at some point you want to insert the list of 'files_used'
"""

 email_body += '\n'.join(files_used)
```

Comment: I think you meant `\n` instead of `/n`.

Comment: @JohnGordon indeed I did, revised accordingly!